# Swift: NSDecimalNumber .decimalNumberByAdding not working, but not failing

Tags: ios, swift, nsdecimalnumber

```
        var sumAmount: NSDecimalNumber = 0.00

        for yy in listItems {

            var selectedItem: NSManagedObject = listItems[idy] as! NSManagedObject

            var thisAmount = selectedItem.valueForKey("amount") as! NSDecimalNumber
            var thisDate = selectedCD.valueForKeyPath("date") as! NSDate

            if thisDate.isGreaterThanDate(NSDate()) {
                if sumAmount == 0.00 {
                    sumAmount = thisAmount
                } else {
                    sumAmount.decimalNumberByAdding(thisAmount)
                }
            }
            idy += 1
        }
```

I am trying to add thisAmount to sumAmount.
Here is a sample of the code. I checked the initial sumAmount for a valid, non nil, setting, this seems correct. But the "add" is just not working. Both number are valid NSDecimalNumbers. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see this earlier. Working to late at night. Thanks.

Comment: sumAmount = sumAmount.decimalNumberByAdding(thisAmount)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers are immutable objects. You have to assign result to variable.